# Switch every pair of characters in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string of numbers 07917142299099F0 and I want to swap every pair of characters. So the string becomes 701917249209990F. I haven't really used Ruby, so I'm not really sure if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: A quartet of small points: 1. When referring to Ruby objects, show them as such (you need quotes around your strings); 2. Always make it clear whether you wish to modify, or *mutate*, the original object (here a string) or to create and return a new object and not mutate the original object ("becomes" is vague); 3. It's more accurate to say "a string of *digits*"; and 4) you can set off the strings, as you would code, by enclosing them in backticks.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 5):

You can use substitution with regex:

```
str.gsub(/(.)(.)/, '\2\1')
```

Comment: ...or `str.gsub(/../, &:reverse)`. Both of these work regardless of whether the string has an even or odd number of characters, in the latter case assuming that the last character is to remain. I prefer my regex, but only because I don't like the way yours is looking at me.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- Get every character from the string as an array.
- Take each pair of elements inside.
- Swap/Reverse them (as they're just two).
- Join the result.

```
'07917142299099F0'
  .chars               # ["0", "7", "9", "1", "7", "1", "4", "2", "2", "9", "9", "0", "9", "9", "F", "0"]
  .each_slice(2)       #<Enumerator: ["0", "7", "9", "1", "7", "1", "4", "2", "2", "9", "9", "0", "9", "9", "F", "0"]:each_slice(2)>
  .flat_map(&:reverse) # ["7", "0", "1", "9", "1", "7", "2", "4", "9", "2", "0", "9", "9", "9", "0", "F"]
  .join                # "701917249209990F"
```

Other way:

```
p str.gsub(/(.{2})/) { Regexp.last_match.to_s.reverse } # "701917249209990F"
```

---

Notice this might not work as expected with an odd number of elements in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer @Sagar's solution, for the sake of variety here's another.

```
def reverse_each_pair(str)
  nbr_even_chars = 2*(str.size/2)
  nbr_even_chars.times.with_object('') do |i,s|
    s[i] = str[i.odd? ? (i-1) : i+1]
  end << str[-1, str.size-nbr_even_chars]
end
```

```
reverse_each_pair '07917142299099F0'
  #=> "701917249209990F" 
reverse_each_pair '07917142299099F'
  #=> "70191724920999F"
```